# Keep the font color for boxes in text or math mode

Tags: color, tcolorbox, box

My goal is for the `enca` command below to use color blue for math and text mode. What's the best way to do this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%BOX
\NewDocumentCommand{\enca}{ O{black} m }{%
    \ifmmode\tcboxmath[standard jigsaw, tcbox raise base,opacityback=0,tcbox width=auto limited,extras={colupper={tcbcolback}},colframe=#1,size=fbox]{#2}\else
     \tcbox[standard jigsaw, tcbox raise base,tcbox width=auto limited,opacityback=0,extras={colupper={tcbcolback}},colframe=#1,size=fbox,nobeforeafter]{#2}\fi%
    }
%
\begin{document}

{\color{blue}

ABCEE \enca{ABCDE}, 
\[ 1 +\enca{\int_1^2 x^2 \mathrm{d} x}.\]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can save the current color and apply to the color box, for example:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\enca}{ O{black} m }{%
    \colorlet{temp}{.}% Save the current color to temp
    \ifmmode\tcboxmath[standard jigsaw, tcbox raise base,opacityback=0,tcbox width=auto limited,colupper=temp,colframe=#1,size=fbox]{#2}\else
     \tcbox[standard jigsaw, tcbox raise base,tcbox width=auto limited,opacityback=0,colupper=temp,colframe=#1,size=fbox,nobeforeafter]{#2}\fi%
    }
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%BOX
\NewDocumentCommand{\enca}{ O{black} m }{%
    \colorlet{temp}{.}%
    \ifmmode\tcboxmath[standard jigsaw, tcbox raise base,opacityback=0,tcbox width=auto limited,colupper=temp,colframe=#1,size=fbox]{#2}\else
     \tcbox[standard jigsaw, tcbox raise base,tcbox width=auto limited,opacityback=0,colupper=temp,colframe=#1,size=fbox,nobeforeafter]{#2}\fi%
    }
%
\begin{document}

{\color{blue}

ABCEE \enca[red]{ABCDE}, 
\[ 1 +\enca[red]{\int_1^2 x^2 \mathrm{d} x}.\]
}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank's ! it works perfectly. I also used `temp` as an optional argument (`O{temp}`) to make the box color match as well.